# How to get IDs from a jQuery DataTable to a ASP.NET MVC controller on HTTPPOST?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, datatables

I have a jQuery DataTable in a MVC View that gets populated on the client side based on some settings that can be set by the user. When a submit button is pressed, I would like to capture this data in the table and post it to a HttpPost web method in my controller.

How can I achieve this?

Edit:

Adding more information. OK, so I have two jQuery Datatables - Table A and table B. On page load, Table A gets populated with data from a view model that I have created. When a user clicks on a row in table A, the row is copied to table B. I would like to capture the rows that have been inserted into table B (or if possible, just one of the columns) and post that data back to my Controller.

Comment: So you want to grab the entire data set that is displayed in the table? In what format is this data originaly recieved

Comment: Basically you want to store the data in a hidden input. I would store the data JSON format, which you can then parse server side when you post the page.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by doing the following:

Created a JavaScript array and each time a row was selected, add the ID of the row to the array. When the Submit button was clicked, use AJAX to post the array to my controller. From here, I was able to deserialize the array and get out the selected IDs.